# Android/Java: open a link in Chrome using a specific tab (not the last one)

Tags: java, android

I know that I can use `EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID` so as not to make chrome always open a new tab, but this has an undesired effect: it will open the URL in the last used tab, which I don't want to.

My intention is this: open the URL in a new tab only for the first time and then always use that tab, independently of whether the user has been navigating to other tabs.

Why I want this: Because I'm getting the copied to clipboard text and I want that text to be searched at a specific URL. So if the user is in some news website and copied a word he wants to be searched for, chrome will be opened at the same tab he was, which is undesired.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: That would mean that the tab automatically navigates away from the results, even if the user wanted to keep that open for later. It's worth considering whether it would be better to leave control at the user and always open a new tab. (But the question is in itself still interesting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's no way to do that (because never getting the index of the opened tab returned - and not being able to tell which tab one wants to remote; this does not work alike a Chrome extension).

**but** you could instead just use a `WebView` - which would provide the desired effect - despite never leaving the app; or even a `WebView` in an overlaid `DialogFragment`, instead of a new `Activity`.